# For GORM Map type, add index to the table created by GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

GORM has below example:

```
class Author {
    Map books // map of ISBN:book names
}
```

When GORM create table, it will create a table with three column: author_books, author_books_idx and author_books_elt

The problem is none of this three column is indexed, and the table doesn't has index on it. It works on MySQL, or may be sql server. But in SQL Azure, it does not works as all table in SQL Azure should have a cluster index, this make I can not insert row to such table.

How to fix such issue? I think add a cluster index on an existing column or add a new private key column should be fine, but I don't know how I can force GORM to create index on it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is simply to create the index in Bootstrap. A log table that keeps track of things done to the database schema has proven useful in one project where I'm involved (the schema changes constantly).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import javax.sql.DataSource

class BootStrap {
    DataSource dataSource

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if (!Author.count()) {
            createIndexes();
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }

    private void createIndexes() {
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("ALTER TABLE author [code for adding an index];")
    }

}
```

This file, the 'BootStrap.groovy' is located in you grails applications's directory/grails-app/conf.
This code checks if the table author is empty (for example created for the first time) and if it is, you can alter the table with SQL queries using the groovy.sql.Sql instance. This way you'll be able to add indexes add columns, etc...